# macOS(10.13.6) npm install error - Failed at the fibers@4.0.3 install script with node version 9.8.0

Tags: node.js, python-2.7, vue.js, npm, webpack

Initially my project setup was working fine for with **node version 9.8.0** and **fibers version ^4.0.1**
but due to a replicate issue I run a very old version of my project codebase, an old code base compile fine and I had done that test, but when I came back to my latest codebase now I am facing below error when doing `npm install.`

I have searched google and tried all possible solution:

1. remove `node_modules`,`package-lock.json` from my project, remove `$HOME/.node-gpy`
2. then did `npm update`, `npm install`
3. `remove /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools`, `xcode-select --install`, `xcode-select --switch /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/` etc.
4. manually `npm install fibers@4`
5. manually `node-gyp rebuild` etc.
   None of this works, after trying for a whole day noting I able to fix it, please let me know if anyone can suggest any solution based on the below logs.

   **Error logs:**

```
fsevents@1.2.13 install /Users/xxx/IdeaProjects/project/folder1/folder2/node_modules/fsevents
node install.js

xcode-select: error: tool 'xcodebuild' requires Xcode, but active developer directory '/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools' is a command line tools instance

xcode-select: error: tool 'xcodebuild' requires Xcode, but active developer directory '/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools' is a command line tools instance

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/gyp/gyp_main.py", line 16, in <module>
    sys.exit(gyp.script_main())
  File "/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/gyp/pylib/gyp/__init__.py", line 545, in script_main
    return main(sys.argv[1:])
  File "/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/gyp/pylib/gyp/__init__.py", line 538, in main
    return gyp_main(args)
  File "/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/gyp/pylib/gyp/__init__.py", line 523, in gyp_main
    generator.GenerateOutput(flat_list, targets, data, params)
  File "/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/gyp/pylib/gyp/generator/make.py", line 2170, in GenerateOutput
    part_of_all=qualified_target in needed_targets)
  File "/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/gyp/pylib/gyp/generator/make.py", line 795, in Write
    self.Pchify))
  File "/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/gyp/pylib/gyp/generator/make.py", line 1190, in WriteSources
    cflags = self.xcode_settings.GetCflags(configname)
  File "/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/gyp/pylib/gyp/xcode_emulation.py", line 551, in GetCflags
    archs = self.GetActiveArchs(self.configname)
  File "/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/gyp/pylib/gyp/xcode_emulation.py", line 420, in GetActiveArchs
    xcode_archs_default = GetXcodeArchsDefault()
  File "/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/gyp/pylib/gyp/xcode_emulation.py", line 118, in GetXcodeArchsDefault
    xcode_version, _ = XcodeVersion()
  File "/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/gyp/pylib/gyp/xcode_emulation.py", line 1265, in XcodeVersion
    version = re.match(r'(\d\.\d\.?\d*)', version).groups()[0]
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'groups'
gyp ERR! configure error 
gyp ERR! stack Error: `gyp` failed with exit code: 1
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onCpExit (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/lib/configure.js:336:16)
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:180:13)
gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:209:12)
gyp ERR! System Darwin 17.7.0
gyp ERR! command "/usr/local/Cellar/node/9.8.0/bin/node" "/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js" "rebuild"
gyp ERR! cwd /Users/xxx/IdeaProjects/project/folder1/folder2/node_modules/fsevents
gyp ERR! node -v v9.8.0
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.6.2
gyp ERR! not ok 

> fibers@4.0.3 install /Users/xxx/IdeaProjects/project/folder1/folder2/node_modules/fibers
> node build.js || nodejs build.js

xcode-select: error: tool 'xcodebuild' requires Xcode, but active developer directory '/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools' is a command line tools instance

xcode-select: error: tool 'xcodebuild' requires Xcode, but active developer directory '/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools' is a command line tools instance

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/gyp/gyp_main.py", line 16, in <module>
    sys.exit(gyp.script_main())
  File "/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/gyp/pylib/gyp/__init__.py", line 545, in script_main
    return main(sys.argv[1:])
  File "/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/gyp/pylib/gyp/__init__.py", line 538, in main
    return gyp_main(args)
  File "/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/gyp/pylib/gyp/__init__.py", line 523, in gyp_main
    generator.GenerateOutput(flat_list, targets, data, params)
  File "/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/gyp/pylib/gyp/generator/make.py", line 2170, in GenerateOutput
    part_of_all=qualified_target in needed_targets)
  File "/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/gyp/pylib/gyp/generator/make.py", line 795, in Write
    self.Pchify))
  File "/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/gyp/pylib/gyp/generator/make.py", line 1190, in WriteSources
    cflags = self.xcode_settings.GetCflags(configname)
  File "/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/gyp/pylib/gyp/xcode_emulation.py", line 551, in GetCflags
    archs = self.GetActiveArchs(self.configname)
  File "/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/gyp/pylib/gyp/xcode_emulation.py", line 420, in GetActiveArchs
    xcode_archs_default = GetXcodeArchsDefault()
  File "/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/gyp/pylib/gyp/xcode_emulation.py", line 118, in GetXcodeArchsDefault
    xcode_version, _ = XcodeVersion()
  File "/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/gyp/pylib/gyp/xcode_emulation.py", line 1265, in XcodeVersion
    version = re.match(r'(\d\.\d\.?\d*)', version).groups()[0]
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'groups'
gyp ERR! configure error 
gyp ERR! stack Error: `gyp` failed with exit code: 1
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onCpExit (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/lib/configure.js:336:16)
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:180:13)
gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:209:12)
gyp ERR! System Darwin 17.7.0
gyp ERR! command "/usr/local/Cellar/node/9.8.0/bin/node" "/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js" "rebuild" "--release"
gyp ERR! cwd /Users/xxx/IdeaProjects/project/folder1/folder2/node_modules/fibers
gyp ERR! node -v v9.8.0
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.6.2
gyp ERR! not ok 
node-gyp exited with code: 1
Please make sure you are using a supported platform and node version. If you
would like to compile fibers on this machine please make sure you have setup your
build environment--
Windows + OS X instructions here: https://github.com/nodejs/node-gyp
Ubuntu users please run: `sudo apt-get install g++ build-essential`
RHEL users please run: `yum install gcc-c++` and `yum groupinstall 'Development Tools'` 
Alpine users please run: `sudo apk add python make g++`
sh: nodejs: command not found
npm WARN ajv-keywords@2.1.1 requires a peer of ajv@^5.0.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.

npm ERR! file sh
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno ENOENT
npm ERR! syscall spawn
npm ERR! fibers@4.0.3 install: `node build.js || nodejs build.js`
npm ERR! spawn ENOENT
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the fibers@4.0.3 install script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
```

Comment: Try reinstalling XCode (as hinted at in the error message).

Comment: @tony19 Thank you for response, I had tried with remove /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools and then xcode-select --install and then xcode-select --switch /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/ etc. but no luck!